# How do I make a list with repeating entries?

Tags: google-sheets

Essentially, I want a formula which creates a list of jobs based on the value given to that job.

Here's an example. [image]

I have a column for jobs which lists Barista and Manager. Then a column for the number of that job that is available, which says there are 3 barista positions and 1 manager position.

The formula I'm trying to have should make a list that repeats "Barista" 3 times and only lists manager once. How would I do this?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sequence()` and `flatten()`, like this:

`=arrayformula( query( flatten( if( sequence(1, max(B2:B)) <= B2:B, A2:A, iferror(1/0) ) ), "where Col1 is not null", 0 ) )`

Comment: Thank you! This does work great! While I'd like to understand how, I do thank you for solving the problem.